# How to display single encrypt record?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I use encrypt. I can display all table data. However I can'T get one record.  I don't encrypt 'id'. I tried another column but same.

Here is my error

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Here is my code

blade file (I click this link first )

```
<a href="one?id={{ $val->id }}">{{ $val->id }}</a>
```

blade file (display page I got error at this page)

```
@foreach ($data as $val)    
{{ $val->id }}
@endforeach
```

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

web.php

```
Route::get('/one','MailController@onerecord');
Route::post('/one','MailController@onerecord');
```

Controller

```
public function onerecord(Request $request)
 { 
$id = $request['id'];
$data = Contact::where('id',$id)->get();
return view('mail.one', ['data' => $data]); 
}
```

Could you teach me what is wrong my code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dd($data)` after retrieving your Contact with `Contact::where('id',$id)->get();` in order to investigate the content of `$data`. Most likely an object is returned and not an array, so looping through `$data` inside your blade `@foreach` will loop through the object's properties. Therefore `$val->id` isn't valid but the direct access of `$data->id` would be, without the need of looping through `$data`.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I did dd($data) and check all my code many times and somehow it works. Thank you very much. I will always use dd($data) first.